# update "DetailTextLabel.text" in a UITableView using delegate from other view-controller in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, delegates

I am learning swift and currently I am experimenting UITableView in a View-Controller.

I want to change DetailLabelText.text for a specific row by receiving an **index number** and **a String** via ***delegate from other view-controller***

I just could not figure out that where to perform this update of row.

```
    class     myView:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,totalContactsAdded  {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func addAGroupBtnclicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   addGroupName()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func getCount(aString: String , anIndex: Int) {

    //  UPDATE SELECTED ROW HERE BUT HOW ?  
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupMgr.groups.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:     NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Groups")

    cell.textLabel?.text = groupMgr.groups[indexPath.row].name
    cell.DetailLabelText?.text = groupMgr.groups[indexPath.row].count
    return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("tocontacts", sender: tableView)
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:  UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){

        groupMgr.groups.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    }




    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "tocontacts" {
        var tab = segue.destinationViewController as TabbarController
        var view = tab.viewControllers?.first as contactsListView
        view.delegate = self
    }
        }
    func toaster(message:String){
    self.view.makeToast(message: message)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Update your data model then reload the row affected using the indexPath. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the text in a specific row you need to alter your data set at that row.

After altering your data set you call

```
yourTableView.reloadData()
```

Make sure to do this on the main thread however, as calling this from any other thread will not update your UI correctly.

You can do this by wrapping it like so

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    yourTableView.reloadData()
})
```

For example changing your data could be done like so:

```
groupMgr.groups[3].name = "Another name"
yourTableView.reloadData()
```

To do this from another ViewController you'll have to make some way of accessing the data outside of your class.